# How to merge two columns of JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I am retriving data from database.TableName:Contacts. There are two fields of this table.First_Name and Last_Name. I want to merge these two columns and want one column of JTable as Full Name.I've tried to create concat sql query,which was:

```
String queryMerge="select (First_Name||Last_Name) as Full_Name from Contacts";
```

But it gave me an error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft access driver] Invalid use of vertical bars in query expression '(First_Name||Last_Name)'
```

I thought to store all retrieved data in vector and use that values to build JTable.I am using AbstractTableModel.Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't really about Swing, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging the data in the SQL query should work fine, you just need to get the syntax right.

Another option is when you are pulling the columns out of the `ResultSet`, combine them before putting them in the table's model.

Comment: Yes I am tring the same but didnt get success yet.Thanks for your support.

Comment: I would personally go with that option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "&" instead of "||" if you really need to do it on query level.
I'm not sure if parentheses are needed.

Comment: Thanks.But its giving an error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Invalid descriptor index

Comment: Isn't the SQL string concatenation operator in Access the `+` sign?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how simplistic this application is.  If you're doing something small, then trying to concatenate in the query is fine.

If this query is going to be used in many different places I really would consider returning the individual fields and then use a custom [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that will do the first and last name concatenation for you.  That way in the future you won't have different sql queries for different views.  Just one query, that is manipulated by the view to display what it needs.  (Hopefully...)